# Conversion from int to char may alter its value

Tags: c++, compilation

This is giving me an error on line 524:35 where it says

```
strcap[i] = tolower (str [i]);
```

saying that the conversion to char from int may alter its value, I have a few errors of these in the source code, so if I can fix this one then the others will be a piece of cake. Can anyone please explain to me in simple terms? I am quite new to this.. Thanks!

```
char *imccapitalize( const char *str )
{
   static char strcap[LGST];
   int i;

   for( i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++ )
   strcap[i] = tolower( str[i] );
   strcap[i] = '\0';
   strcap[0] = toupper( strcap[0] );
   return strcap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Many C "character" functions in fact take and return `int`s as characters. (This is so they can return special values such as `EOF`, and also because this practice got set in stone before people noticed that type safety was a good thing.) `toupper` and `tolower` are two of these functions. The [declaration](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/tolower.html) for `tolower` is:

```
int tolower(int c);
```

So to get rid of these warnings, you have to typecast the return value:

```
strcap[i] = (char) tolower( str[i] );
```

Comment: To be clear , it is a compiler bug that this warning occurs, and we put in the cast to shut the compiler up.   If the compiler allows you to disable this warning entirely, my preference is to do that, rather than mangling your code with spurious casts.

Comment: Yeah, usually this kind of warn-on-value-altering-casts stuff is only supposed to happen with C++, but some compilers accidentally leak these "features" into the C side.

Answer (score 2):

It should be a warning, not an error (however most compilers have an option to treat warnings 
as errors, so if that option is being used an error will be produced).

The warning is generated because `tolower` returns `int`, which is common for the C runtime library character manipulation functions. Assigning an `int` to `char` can result in truncation of the value since on most machines a `char` is one-byte and an `int` is two or more, hence the warning.

A typecast will eliminate the warning:

```
strcap[i] = (char)tolower(str[i]);
```

Comment: @MikeDeSimone Quite true (I always do). Edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Integers are represented using more bytes than chars do. Therefore if you try to turn an integer to a char you will have to get rid of the extra bytes ,potentially altering the integer's value.